# Method Priority in testng

Tags: testng

I'm facing problem in running test method on basis of priority. Below is my code snip

```
Class TestHarness{
      @BeforeSuite
      setUP(){ }

      @AfterSuite
      tearDown(){}
}

XYZ extends TestHarness{

      @Test(Priority=1)
      verifyXYZ{}
}

ABC extends TestHarness{
      @Test(Priority=2)
      verifyABC{}
}
```

Testng.xml

```
<suite name="SmokeTestSuite">
  <listener class-name="TestResultListener" />
    <test name="SmokeTests" >
      <classes>
        <class name="XYZ" />             
        <class name="ABC"/>                 
      </classes>
    </test>
 </suite>
```

`ABC.verifyABC()` methods gets executes prior of `XYZ.verifyXYZ()`. Even though `preserve-order` has not set with false in `testng.xml`.

Main intention to run all test on basis of test class order defined in `testng.xml`. Tried below solutions but didn't work:

1. re-priority test methods of all classes(in `testng.xml`) by extending `IMethodInterceptor`.

   Result: In this case execution order was,

   ```
       i. BeforeSuite Method 
      ii. ABC.verifyABC method
     iii. override intercept method
   ```
2. Specified priority on all test methods of all the test classes but somehow this also didn't work for me.

I'm using testng 6.11 version. Can anybody help me out in this context.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`preserve-order` is less important than `priority`:

> Hierarchy on order features (from less important to more important): groupByInstance, preserveOrder, priority, dependsOnGroups, dependsOnMethods

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L75

So TestNG will respect `priority` before `preserve-order` in the case of conflict.

If you remove priorities, then TestNG is supposed to respect `preserve-order` and run tests according to the suite file.